# Standard deviation of a file in python - *UPDATED*

Tags: python

So I need to create a program that will open a file and take the standard deviation and mean of the numbers with a mean and standard deviation function I created for prior problems in my problem set.

I know my mean and standard deviation functions work because I did fine on the other questions, but those weren't using files - they were using lists I had created in the program.

I have successfully opened the file, but the problem is that I am having a hard time converting the contents of the file to a list of integers.

The file has 8 values - one of which is not numeric and I have made an exception for that.

This is the code I have so far:

```
numlist = [10, 13, 24, 8, 16, 17]
phrase = ['Could not calculate "my_mean" because vector was submitted empty.']

def my_mean(A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return phrase
    else:
        mean = float(sum(A)) / len(A)
        return mean

import math

def vari(B):
    mean = my_mean(B)
    length = len(B)
    temp = 0
    for i in range(length):
        temp += (B[i] - mean) * (B[i] - mean)
    return temp / length

def my_sd(B):
    return math.sqrt(vari(B))

import statistics

f = open('pythonfile.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
add = 0
count = 0
for line in lines:
    try:
      level = float(line)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    add += level
    count += 1
    newmean = add/float(count)
print("average:", newmean);
```

Comment: (1) Pleasd repair the formatting. (2) Why not just read the numbers into a list first and process that?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

use

```
lines = f.read().split()
```

and leave everything else as it is.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my issue was that I should be using my old functions I created and I have no idea how to convert the values from my file into a list of integers. Every time I have tried, I get several lines of lists of single integers. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: @lilkiosk you may upvote and / or accept the answer if you find it useful =)